# Speeding up the search in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called  `real_info` which has 3 columns for example:

```
  Source   Target Interaction
0  MAP7D1    APOA1    physical
1  MAP7D1    RBM48    physical
2  MAP7D1  GPRASP1    physical
3  MAP7D1    COPS6    physical
4   USP20   MAP7D1    physical
```

I indexed these columns like this into a new dataframe thinking that search will be fast:

```
new_df = real_info.set_index(['Source','Target','Interaction'])
```

I have 5000 name_list of string where I am searching the pair of this in the `new_df`. If there is a match then I am storing in a file  for example:

```
for names_A in name_list:
    for names_B in name_list:
        res = df.query('Source == "{}" & Target == "{}"'.format(names_A,names_B))
        if len(res.index.tolist()) > 0:
            res.to_csv('nets.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

This process works but it is very slow to search pairs for 5000 X 5000 list. Is there any suggestion to improve this?

Comment: Can you post an example of a data set (`name_list`) that you want use for searching? Also please post your desired data set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually halfway there. Lot's of appreciation to MaxU, borrowing data from his post.

---

**Step 1**
Indexing is a good option, but let's just index the first two columns:

```
df = df.set_index(['Source', 'Target'])
df

              Interaction
Source Target            
a      z         physical
b      c         physical
c      x         physical
d      y         physical
e      b         physical
b      a         physical
```

**Step 2**
Generate all possible combinations:

```
import itertools

c = list(itertools.product(name_list, name_list))
c


[('a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('b', 'b'),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'b'),
 ('c', 'c')]
```

**Step 3**
Index into your dataframe, and save:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.intersection(c)].reset_index()
df

  Source Target Interaction
0      b      a    physical
1      b      c    physical

df.to_csv('nets.csv')
```

This option is one to choose if you have two or more `name_list`s from where you need to find combinations, rather than taking elements from a single `name_list`, in which case, you would choose MaxU's answer.

Comment: Im still not understanding the question. But I understand the answer.

Comment: @Bharath They want to retrieve rows which have matching Source-Target pairs in their `name_list` I think.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, i also understood it this way. First i wanted to use cartesian product as well, but then i realized that if we will use cartesian product of a sinlge list (`name_list`), then OP simply wants to check whether either `Source` or `Target` matches an element from the `name_list`. How do you think - does it make sense?

Comment: @MaxU I think it does... but in that case you'd need `... & ...`, not `.... | ...` Since it has to be in both source as well as target.

Comment: @MaxU If name_list has [a, b, c], you'd want to find [(a, b), (b, c), and (a, c)] (and all associated permutations). If there is a (a, x) or (b, y) pair in your df, it is still picked.

Comment: I thought about this answer as a general case (two separate lists), didn't realise it could be so simplified for one list as your code has shown.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I felt the same. Since looping of name_list is under name_list only, we might need `&` rather than `|`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, yeah, you are absolutely right! thanks for the clear example!

Comment: Thanks @COLDSPEED, for such a clear explanation.  It solved my problem and speed up the process. I accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC: (thanks a lot to @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and @Bharath for pointing to the error!)

```
res = df.loc[df['Source'].isin(name_list) & df['Target'].isin(name_list)]
res.to_csv(...)
```

Demo:

```
In [312]: df
Out[312]:
  Source Target Interaction
0      a      z    physical
1      b      c    physical
2      c      x    physical
3      d      y    physical
4      e      b    physical
5      b      a    physical

In [313]: name_list
Out[313]: ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [314]: df.loc[df['Source'].isin(name_list) & df['Target'].isin(name_list)]
Out[314]:
  Source Target Interaction
1      b      c    physical
5      b      a    physical
```

Comment: Sir as coldspeed said we might need `&` here. Pairs on name_list will not be possible if you use |. If target is in name_list and source is not in name_list that pair would be selected too.